# Elastic search Multiple Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two elastic search queries

1. For Get transaction information for a particular day
2. For get transaction information for all days

How can i combine these two quires into a single query? Am struggling to write a signle query for these two similar needs. Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "payment_type": "paypal"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "transaction_date": {
            "from": "2014-11-10",
            "to": "2014-11-10"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_price_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    },
    "daily_post_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "purchased_post_count"
      }
    }
  }
}


{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "payment_type": "paypal"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_price_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    },
    "daily_post_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "purchased_post_count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using ES of version less than 1.4.0, you can make use of [Filter Aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html). Query for the same is as below:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "payment_type": "paypal"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "daily_price_sum": {
         "sum": {
            "field": "price"
         }
      },
      "daily_post_sum": {
         "sum": {
            "field": "purchased_post_count"
         }
      },
      "one_day_aggs": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "transaction_date": {
                  "from": "2014-11-10",
                  "to": "2014-11-10"
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "daily_price_sum": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "price"
               }
            },
            "daily_post_sum": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "purchased_post_count"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But if you are using ES 1.4.0, then you can use [Filters Aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) to make the query more compact. Query for the same is as below:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "payment_type": "paypal"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "transactions": {
         "filters": {
            "filters": {
               "one_day": {
                  "range": {
                     "transaction_date": {
                        "from": "2014-11-10",
                        "to": "2014-11-10"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "all_days": {
                  "match_all": {}
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "daily_price_sum": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "price"
               }
            },
            "daily_post_sum": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "purchased_post_count"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I also see that you are not interested in the query hits but only on the aggregation values. In that case, you can improve the performance of these aggregations by making use of [Shard Query Cache](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-shard-query-cache.html) which is present in ES 1.4.0. For making use of this, enable shard query cache as mentioned in the link and add the following parameter to the `_search` operation:
`search_type=count`.

Comment: Thank you @Mouzer first query worked for me. Thank you so much for your help and support. I will check Shard Query Cache.

Comment: hi @bittusarkar : Is it possible to add the "order" clause in the parent aggregation based on any one of the child agg? For example, if i want to order by the avg of daily_post_sum? I am facing a problem in which my results are getting aggregated by any one sub agg and not both.....Thanks !

Comment: Didn't know about the possibility of multiple filters. Perfect for my case!